# combination multiple statements in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I read that "Multiple statements can be separated by commas. In the following example, the inc() function is used to increment the value of a global variable counter. Note the combination of the the two statements: i++, inc():"

I don't understand how this code works to give me 10 as a result

```js
let counter = 0;
function inc() {
  counter++;
}
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++, inc());
console.log(counter); //the result is 10
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? Seems pretty basic. You have a variable and a function. You create a loop that calls that function 10 times

Comment: You answered your on question in it : "I read that "Multiple statements can be separated by commas".
You invoked function inc based on Multiple statements when separated it using comma

Answer (score 0):

This will make you understand what is going on:

```js
let counter = 0;
function inc(i) {
  console.log('incremented i = '+ i + " -- counter (not yet incremented)= " + counter)
  counter++;
}
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++, inc(i));
console.log('counter incremented = ' + counter); //the result is 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a function named inc(), and you call it only from the for loop(for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++, inc());). In the loop, you call it 10 times, and then it will print once the value of the counter(line 4).

Answer (score 0):

so basically we got variable with value of zero and function that increments that variable.
then we iterate a loop and until variable "i" is not incremeneted enough to become 10 we call that function that increments counter variable.first time for loop checks if "i" is still less then 10 or not, it is not because `i=0` so it calls a function that increments counter until `i>=10` and because `i=0` at the beginning it gives counter result as 10 (if `i=1` at the beginning it would give you 9 as result) if it is still observe, you could just increment counter straight forward. i think this will help you